# PowerShell 3 regular expression - why is case insensitive not working?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to figure out why the below code won't match when the case is different. The reason for the 3rd/4th line is to combine my log filters into one expression, while still allowing commas.

I've tried a bunch of different ways, but case still matters.

```
$combined_log = {"A", "B", "Error"}
$Log_Filters = "ERROR", "failed", "Note", "Warning"
#[regex]$Log_Filter_regex =  '(?i)^(' + (($Log_Filters|foreach{[regex]::escape($_) -replace ",","\,"}) –join "|") + ')$'
[regex]$Log_Filter_regex =  (($Log_Filters|foreach {[regex]::escape($_) -replace ",","\,"}) –join "|") 
$combined_log | where {$_ -imatch $Log_Filter_regex}
```

Comment: Remove `[regex]` from the start of the 4th line. `[regex]$Log_Filter_regex` > `$Log_Filter_regex`. `-imatch` should be followed with a string pattern.

Comment: Seriously?  That's IT?  Dang.  Okay, @WiktorStribiżew , if you want to put it as an answer I'll mark you as the solution. Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: @mbourgon You can use `[regex]` object with `-match` operator, but then it will derive case sensitivity from `[regex]` object's own options, not from operator: `$regex = New-Object regex 'String', 'IgnoreCase'; 'sTRING' -cmatch $regex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-match` / `-imatch` operators expect a string pattern to follow, so remove `[regex]` from the code line:

```
$Log_Filter_regex =  (($Log_Filters|foreach {[regex]::escape($_) -replace ",","\,"}) –join "|")
```

The pattern will look like `ERROR|failed|Note|Warning` and you will get the match.

[image]